# find members with canceled subscriptions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

So, Members have many subscriptions. A member is canceled if the last subscription canceled_at is not nil. But I can't seem to get the query to work right, to find all members with presently canceled subscriptions.

I'm doing this in the member model

```
  scope :canceled, includes(:subscriptions).
    where('subscriptions.canceled_at IS NOT NULL')
```

but it returns for users who have previously canceled subscriptions too. I need to use limit or something like that, I have the relation defined as

```
has_many :subscriptions, :order => "subscriptions.created_at DESC", :dependent => :destroy
```

so i can just work offf the .first, but not sure how to apply that logic to the class scope like that.

Comment: still not entirely clear, you want to find users whose subscriptions are presently canceled ?  Whats the difference between presently cancelled subscriptions and the past ones? Is their a date range?

Comment: users who's latest subscription record status is canceled, which is denoted by canceled_at being null or with a datetime obj

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another association

```
 Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :last_subscription, :class_name => "Subscription", :foreign_key => "member_id", :order => "created_at desc"
```

Then try

```
 scope :canceled, includes(:last_subscription).where('subscriptions.canceled_at IS NOT NULL')
```

Comment: that comes out to SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` ORDER BY members.last_name ASC, members.first_name ASC LIMIT 1  so it only returns 1 member

Comment: try calling it with Member.includes(:last_subscripton).all. That query executed doesnt make sense, not sure why it isnt calling subscriptions

Comment: ok, did that, then ran:  Member.canceled.all.each do |m|; p m.full_name unless m.subscriptions.first.canceled?; end and i returned a few members, which i shouldn't in theory

Comment: I am testing it out on my machine and I get a different query, what does m = member.first     m.last_subscription give you?

Comment: I dont think its possible to eager load the most recent objects, you will have to do raw sql, check this past answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: yes, it returns only one subscription which is most recent, which could be a cancled or active subscription. checking out link now