# Need Help Speeding up an Aggregate SQLite Query

Tags: mysql, performance, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table defined like the following...

```
CREATE table actions (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  end BOOLEAN,
  type VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  subtype_a VARCHAR(15),
  subtype_b VARCHAR(15),
);
```

I'm trying to query for the last end action of some type to happen on each unique `(subtype_a, subtype_b)` pair, similar to a group by (except SQLite doesn't say *what* row is guaranteed to be returned by a group by).

On an SQLite database of about 1MB, the query I have now can take **upwards of two seconds**, but I need to speed it up to take under a second (since this will be called frequently).

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM actions a_out 
WHERE id = 
  (SELECT MAX(a_in.id) FROM actions a_in 
   WHERE a_out.subtype_a = a_in.subtype_a 
     AND a_out.subtype_b = a_in.subtype_b 
     AND a_in.status IS NOT NULL 
     AND a_in.type = "some_type");
```

If it helps, I know all the unique possibilities for a `(subtype_a,subtype_b)`

eg:

```
(a,1)
(a,2)
(b,3)
(b,4)
(b,5)
(b,6)
```

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag, and since there's a limit of five tags I had to replace one of the tags you listed.  I replaced `sqlite`, because your table definition is MySQL specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with version 3.7.11, SQLite [guarantees](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) which record is returned in a group:

> Queries of the form: "SELECT max(x), y FROM table" returns the value of y on the same row that contains the maximum x value.

So [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) can be implemented in a much simpler way:

```
SELECT *, max(id)
FROM actions
WHERE type = 'some_type'
GROUP BY subtype_a, subtype_b
```

Comment: What if you run `SELECT *, MAX(id), MIN(id) ...`?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks; I did realize I have sqlite 3.7.15.

My query is now over 3 seconds faster on large datasets!

Answer (score 0):

Is this any faster?

```
select * from actions where id in (select  max(id) from actions where type="some_type" group by subtype_a, subtype_b);
```

Comment: No, see what I posted in my question about SQLite and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I know, but this query should work in sqlite, since you are expliciting which one you want from the group. Anyway, I did a quick profile and is not fast, Bill Karwin's answer is great.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `greatest-in-per-group` problem that comes up frequently on StackOverflow.

Here's how I solve it:

```
SELECT a_out.* FROM actions a_out
LEFT OUTER JOIN actions a_in ON a_out.subtype_a = a_in.subtype_a 
    AND a_out.subtype_b = a_in.subtype_b
    AND a_out.id < a_in.id
WHERE a_out.type = "some type" AND a_in.id IS NULL
```

If you have an index on (type, subtype_a, subtype_b, id) this should run very fast.

---

See also my answers to similar SQL questions:

- [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481#123481)
- [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/1313293#1313293)
- [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/2111420#2111420)

Or this brilliant article by Jan Kneschke: [Groupwise Max](http://jan.kneschke.de/2007/2/15/groupwise-max/).

Comment: This won't return the latest added (highest autoincrement id) for each group of subtype_a,subtype_b

Comment: @palako, my mistake, I got the inequality backwards.  I have edited to correct it.  It should try to match a greater id value in a_in, and if none is found, then a_out must have the largest id for the respective group.

Comment: No problem. This is actually very fast.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I'll give this a try soon, thanks.

Can you please explain the `a_in.id IS NULL` part?

Comment: For some reason this query returns 0 rows for me.

Comment: Well, I just tested it on MySQL 5.5, and my solution works.  I guess you don't have any rows where type = "some type".

Comment: Bill, I have updated my query; I forgot the "IS NOT NULL" from my original query.

Can you please check if your query still applies? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Blaskovicz, please click the `greatest-n-per-group` tag and read answers given to other questions.  This type of SQL problem has come up dozens of times on Stack Overflow.