# Selecting the latest entry from Table1 which isn't *later* than an entry from Table2

Tags: sql, select, outer-join

Suppose I have a table...

**Calibrations**:

- Date
- CalibrationFactor

and another table...

**Readings**:

- Date
- Reading

Readings are made regularly... calibrations (which don't *alter* subsequent readings, but just figure out how much the readings are off at the time of the calibration) happen infrequently. So, at any given time, a reading needs to be corrected by whatever the *most-recent* CalibrationFactor is. I don't need this correction to be done *by* the SELECT statement; I just want them in the same row.

So, I'd like some SELECT which will give me:
  Readings.Date, Readings.Reading, Calibrations.CalibrationFactor
where the CalibrationFactor is the latest one which is *still* earlier than Readings.Date. I've looked at some of the previous questions, here, but the closest I've found is one which would only find the *latest* calibration, period ([SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship))

Ideas?

Comment: How does the link you include *not* solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out the tweak:

```
SELECT R.Date, R.Reading, C1.CalibrationFactor
FROM Readings R
JOIN Calibrations C1 ON C1.Date < R.Date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Calibrations C2 ON C2.Date < R.Date AND C1.Date < C2.Date
WHERE C2.Date is NULL
```

The first JOIN joins Calibrations on all dates which are *before* the date of the given reading. So, for example (I'll use day names for readability. Assume readings were taken on Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday):

```
R.Date | C1.Date
Friday | Monday
Friday | Tuesday
Friday | Wednesday
```

The second LEFT OUTER JOIN joins Calibrations again, on all dates which are (like the first join) *before* the date of the reading, but *after* the date in C1...

```
R.Date | C1.Date   | C2.Date
Friday | Monday    | Tuesday
Friday | Monday    | Wednesday
Friday | Tuesday   | Wednesday
Friday | Wednesday | NULL
```

Only in the case in which C2.Date will be null will be when there is **no** date in C2 which is both *after* C1.Date *and* still before the reading, which means that C1 will be the most-recent row... thus, the "WHERE C2.Date IS NULL"

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you linked gives you pretty much what you need - but if you want another way you can try (mysql version)

```
select reading.dated, reading.reading, ( 
  select  factor 
  from calibration 
  where calibration.dated < reading.dated
  order by calibration.dated desc limit 1 
) factor
from reading
```

See this [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ec9b/2/0)

Comment: Yeah, the question I linked to was pretty much it... I just didn't see, initially, how to keep it from giving me the *overall* latest calibration, and not the most-recent-before-the-reading. Thanks for the sub-select solution, though.