# Propel 1.6 Greatest n per group

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, propel

I need to build propel query that can get the latest purchase of client

Please use these table/column names in your answer:

- customer: id, name
- purchase: id, customer_id, date

from this question here [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

I need to build propel query based one of these queries:

> 

```
SELECT c.*, p1.*
FROM customer c
JOIN purchase p1 ON (c.id = p1.customer_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase p2 ON (c.id = p2.customer_id AND 
    (p1.date < p2.date OR p1.date = p2.date AND p1.id < p2.id))
WHERE p2.id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT  c.*, p.*
FROM    customer c INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_id,
                    MAX(date) MaxDate
            FROM    purchase
            GROUP BY customer_id
        ) MaxDates ON c.id = MaxDates.customer_id INNER JOIN
        purchase p ON   MaxDates.customer_id = p.customer_id
                    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.date
```

Comment: Could you tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Yes. But nothing for now. Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship
but I can't translate it to propel Query

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your question (finding latest purchase for a given client) then you just want to do a search on the purchase table ordering by date and limiting to one:

```
$lastPurchase = PurchaseQuery::create()
  ->filterByCustomerId($customerId)
  ->orderByDate(Criteria::DESC)
  ->limit(1)
  ->find();
```

The answer you link to, however, is finding all customers AND their latest purchase. In that case I would probably use a custom SQL query (although you technically can do this with Propel functions, it would be more difficult and would not get you very much since you won't be hydrating objects (at least, not easily).

UPDATE
Here's some information on [doing a manual query](http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#using-custom-sql). Note that when doing so, the data returned will NOT be Propel objects, but you can do [on-demand hydration](http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#collections-and-on-demand-hydration) if needed.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.*, p1.*
        FROM customer c
        JOIN purchase p1 ON (c.id = p1.customer_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase p2 ON (c.id = p2.customer_id AND 
            (p1.date < p2.date OR p1.date = p2.date AND p1.id < p2.id))
        WHERE p2.id IS NULL;";
$conn = Propel::getConnection(CustomerPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $someField = $result['...'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get all clients even those without purchase.

Comment: Ok, may want to update the question with that information (I see that you added the example SQL query, but it would help to know what you want in the return data). Also, my recommendation is still that you should do this in a manual query (I'll add some more info in the answer).