# Find most recent joined record in a many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

**Run a SQL query which pulls up a list of invoices including its most recent transaction.**

Requirements:

- get this information using 1 query (inner queries might be necessary)
- include invoices that do not have a transaction yet
- able to filter by fields on the invoice or transaction. example scenarios below:

  - example 1: all invoices whose last transaction status is `settled`
  - example 2: all invoices whose status is `unpaid` which do not have a last transaction)

The tricky part is that we are dealing with a many-to-many scenario.  All StackOverflow posts I found were regarding one-to-many scenarios. The following SO post seemed to take me in the right direction, but could not quiet figure it out: [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

The reason I have a many-to-many here is because a transactions can be part of many invoices.  Basically several invoices can be assigned to the same payment profile, therefore we create one transaction (instead of having a separate transactions for each invoice).  In addition, an invoice can have many transactions since transactions can be declined.

I know you may think, why not have an overarching invoice and then have the current invoices be invoice_lines, or something along those lines, but unfortunately the schema cannot be changed at this time.

Here is an outline my tables:

[image: Diagram]

Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: And where did you get stuck? It shouldn't be too difficult to find the newest transaction to any given invoice_id. Then you've only got to join your invoice table on this column.

Comment: @VMai, I am looking to do this with one query so I can run reports on invoices with filters (if that makes sense).

Comment: @VMAI to be more specific, something like "SELECT * WHERE invoice.amount > 50" or something like it.

Answer (score 1):

Take Bill Karwins approach to solve this kind of problems to find the most recent transaction for any invoice_id:

```
SELECT
    it.invoice_id,
    t1.*
FROM
    invoice_transaction it
INNER JOIN
    transaction t1
ON
    it.transaction_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    transaction t2
ON
    (it.transaction_id = t2.id
AND
    (t1.created_at < t2.created_at OR t1.created_at = t2.created_at AND t1.id < t2.id))
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL
```

gives you t1 as the most recent transaction for that invoice_id. So you've only got to join the invoice table to get the details of this invoice:

```
SELECT
    i.*
    it.invoice_id,
    t1.*
FROM
    invoice_transaction it
-- we can add our join to the invoice table here
INNER JOIN
    invoice i
ON
    it.invoice_id = i.id
-- and we're done
INNER JOIN
    transaction t1
ON
    it.transaction_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    transaction t2
ON
    (it.transaction_id = t2.id
AND
    (t1.created_at < t2.created_at OR t1.created_at = t2.created_at AND t1.id < t2.id))
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL
```

Now you can filter for invoices with a certain amount or those that are due on a certain date as you want by adding this to the `WHERE` clause.

That's what I meant it should not be too difficult to adapt the solution you did already find here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @VMai!  This is a good start, but I am not sure how this will work when an invoice has no transactions yet.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Roeland Begin with table invoice and do a left join to the first query I rewrote from Bill Karwins example. Because the `WHERE` clause does only a check with `IS NULL` there's no need to rewrite this to the `ON` clause of the left join. An invoice without a transaction can't have a most recent transaction, because there isn't one at all.

Comment: So are you saying, if the invoice does not have a transaction, it will not show the invoice?  I was hoping to be able to pull up all invoices with or without a last transaction.

Comment: With the left join it will show the transaction, sure.