# jpa criteria-api: join with subselect

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

This query is used to retrieve last records in a one-to-many relationship (see 
[SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship))

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    customer c 
        INNER JOIN (
                      SELECT customer_id, MAX(date) MaxDate
                      FROM purchase
                      GROUP BY customer_id
                    ) MaxDates ON c.id = MaxDates.customer_id 
        INNER JOIN purchase p ON MaxDates.customer_id = p.customer_id
                    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.date;
```

My question:
How can I build this join with the subselect with the jpa criteria-api? Is it possible? If not, possible with jpql?

My code so far:

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Purchase> query = cb.createQuery(Purchase.class);
final Root<CustomerEntity> root = query.from(Customer.class);

// here should come the join with the sub-select

final Path<Purchase> path = root.join(Customer_.purchases);
query.select(path);

final TypedQuery<Purchase> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to solve that for reference and exercise, although you probably no longer need it after >3 years. Can you give the table structure of the tables, please?

Answer (score 1):

With JPA2.0 a query like this could not be implemented, but we can solve it by restructuring the query

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    customer c 
        /* This part gets the maximum date of a customer purchase
           We will replace it with a subquery in the where
        INNER JOIN (
                      SELECT customer_id, MAX(date) MaxDate
                      FROM purchase
                      GROUP BY customer_id
                    ) MaxDates ON c.id = MaxDates.customer_id */
        /* This part crosses the maximum date of a customer with the purchase itself to obtain the information
        INNER JOIN purchase p ON MaxDates.customer_id = p.customer_id
                    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.date*/
-- We make the crossing with the purchase (there will be N tickets per customer, with N being the number of purchases)
INNER JOIN purchase p on p.customer_id = c.id
-- In the where clause we add a condition so that these N entries become that of the     maximum date
WHERE p.date = (
    SELECT MAX(p2.date)
    FROM purchase p2
    WHERE p2.customer_id = c.id)
;
```

the implementation with criteria-api would be like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Purchase> query = cb.createQuery(Purchase.class);
Root<Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);
Join<Customer,Purchase> join = root.join(root.get("purchases"),JoinType.INNER);

Subquery<Date> sqMaxdate = cq.subquery();
Root<Purchase> sqRoot = sqMaxDate.from(Purchase.class);
Join<Purchase,Consumer> sqJoin = sqRoot.join(sqRoot.get("customer"),JoinType.INNER)
sqMaxDate.select(cb.max(sqRoot.get("date")));
sqMaxDate.where(cb.equal(sqJoin.get("id"),root.get("id")));

query.where(cb.equal(join.get("date"),sqMaxDate.getSelection()));
query.select(join);

TypedQuery<Purchase> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```