# Rails active record query: rendering only the most recent child object (ordered by child created_at date) in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A Parent has_many :children. I want to render each Parent's last child, ordered by the child's created_at date. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with active record & rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
youngest_kids = Parent.includes( :children ).map { |parent| parent.children.last }.compact
```

`compact` removes the `nil`s returned for `parent`s without `children`

Comment: Thanks! Just saw this

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Parents.all.each do |parent|
  parent.children.order(:created_at).last
end
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I was trying to think of a way to do it quicker, with a single DB query

Comment: In that case follow instructions here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Any idea how to convert that to an AR friendly query?