# Find latest matching item in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Consider the following two tables, named `tbl_users` and `tbl_actions` respectively:

```
user_id     user_name     capture_date
u123        John Smith       2016-04-01
u124        Hannah Montana   2015-10-07
u125        James Bond       2014-07-28


user_id     user_alias      use_date
u123         Jonathan Smith  2012-01-01
u125         Double-O Seven  2012-02-04
u125         O-O-Seven       2015-11-25
```

I want to join them such that I would find the "latest used" alias of each user that is before their capture date. So the expected output is:

```
user_id     user_name     capture_date   latest_alias_by_then
u123        John Smith       2016-04-01     Jonathan Smith
u124        Hannah Montana   2015-10-07
u125        James Bond       2014-07-28     Double-O Seven
```

How do you do that efficiently in SQL? I am using Microsoft SQL Server so functions like OVER and RANK are available too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  u.*, a.user_alias,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY a.use_date DESC) rn
        FROM    tbl_users u
        LEFT JOIN
                tbl_actions a
        ON      a.user_id = u.user_id
                AND a.use_date <= u.capture_date
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_users u
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                user_alias
        FROM    tbl_actions a
        WHERE   a.user_id = u.user_id
                AND a.use_date <= u.capture_date
        ORDER BY
                use_date DESC
        ) q
```

Create an index on `tbl_actions (user_id, use_date)` for the queries to work faster.

Either of these methods can be more efficient than the other, depending on how many users and how many actions per user you have.