# T-SQL Grouping Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables.

### Contacts

```
ContactID pk
EmailAddress
FirstName
LastName
Address
```

### Orders

```
OrderID pk
ContactID fk
```

I want to get the number or orders for each email address in Contacts like below

```
select 
    Contacts.EmailAddress,
    count(distinct Orders.OrderID) AS NumOrders
from 
    Contacts inner join Orders on Contacts.ContactID = Orders.ContactID
group by 
    Contacts.EmailAddress
```

Problem is, I also want the first name, last name, address.  But I can't group by those because each email address in Contacts could have a different first name, lastname or address associated with it.

ie:

myname@email.com, Fred, Jackson, 123 Main St
myname@email.com, Bob, Smith, 456 Spruce St.

How can I change my query so that I can get the first name, last name and address for the most recent entry made in Contacts for that email address?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join: selecting the last records in a one-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Can you provide your date column that we can use to find the most recent entry?

Comment: Is it fair to say that "most recent entry" would have the highest contactID? you don't include schema so we can see datatypes, PK definitions, etc.

Comment: Yes, "most recent entry" would have highest contactid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought would be to use windowed functions.

```
SELECT  EmailAddress,
        FirstName,
        Lastname,
        [Address],
        EmailOrderCount
FROM    (SELECT c.EmailAddress,
                c.FirstName,
                c.LastName,
                c.[Address],
                COUNT(o.OrderID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EmailAddress) EmailOrderCount,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.EmailAddress ORDER BY c.ContactID DESC) Rn
        FROM    Contacts c
                JOIN Orders o ON c.ContactID = o.ContactID
        ) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/OTI30976)</kbd>

another way would be to use CROSS APPLY to append the top 1 contact record to the summary rows.

```
SELECT  c.EmailAddress,
        COUNT(o.OrderID) NumOrders,
        ca.FirstName,
        ca.LastName,
        ca.[Address]
FROM    Contacts c
        INNER JOIN Orders ON c.ContactId = o.ContactID
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 
                    FirstName,
                    Lastname,
                    [Address]
            FROM    Contacts c2
            WHERE   c2.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress
            ORDER BY c2.ContactID DESC) ca
GROUP BY c.EmailAddress,
        ca.FirstName,
        ca.LastName,
        ca.[Address]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    Contacts.Name,
    Contacts.FirstName,
    Contacts.LastName
    Contacts.EmailAddress,
    count(distinct Orders.OrderID) AS NumOrders
from 
    (
        select max(ContactID) as ContactID,
        EmailAddress
        from Contacts 
        group by EmailAddress
    ) MinContactForEachEMailAddress
    inner join 
    Contacts 
    on MinContactForEachEMailAddress.ContactID = Contacts.ContactID
    inner join 
    Orders 
    on Contacts.ContactID = Orders.ContactID
group by 
    Contacts.EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to make your original query a subquery and select from it.  I'm making a slight change, because it's a better practice to group by your primary key than your email address.  (Is it a safe bet that each contact has just one email address, and that the basic intent is to group by person?)  If so, try this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.EmailAddress, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Address, sub.NumOrders
 FROM
 (
      select 
          Contacts.ContactID
          count(distinct Orders.OrderID) AS NumOrders
      from 
          Contacts inner join Orders on Contacts.ContactID = Orders.ContactID
      group by 
          Contacts.ContactID
 ) sub
 JOIN Contacts c
 ON sub.ContactID = c.ContactID
```

If you really need to group by email address instead, then change the above subquery to your original query and change c.EmailAddress to sub.EmailAddress.  Of course you may order the SELECT fields however best suits you.

Edit follows:

The ContactID must be a sequence number and you can continually put the same person in the table.  So if you add the DISTINCT keyword in the outer query I believe that will give you what you need.

Comment: I need to group by email address.  Email address isn't unique in the Contact table....that is really the big issue.  The same email address can exist for multiple contactId's.  I did what you said above, but, I still get more than 1 record per email address returned.

Comment: So just to clarify, more than one contact can have the same email address?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get what you want is using a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and taking the "maximum" row by using [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjVpabE0q_MAhXFkiwKHXLCCgQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms186734.aspx&usg=AFQjCNF80R8zK_CIPIcKmIVIcLL0CRHLlA&sig2=rAeKCrYRt9sUNGq-B-NEig&bvm=bv.120551593,d.bGg&cad=rja).

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT C.ContactId, C.Name, C.FirstName, C.LastName, C.EmailAddress, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress ORDER BY ContactId DESC) RowNo
    FROM Contact C 
)
SELECT CTE.*, COUNT(o.OrderID) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.EmailAddress) Cnt
FROM CTE
    JOIN Orders O on CTE.ContactID = O.ContactID
-- select the "maximum" row
WHERE CTE.RowNo = 1
```