# Retrieve a ActiveRecord Relation with a DISTINCT column, taking the first instance of a column's sort with the same relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Having trouble with the below query:

- I have a `surveys` table
- The `surveys` table has a foreign key to a `contact` (via `contact_id`)
- There are mutiple `surveys` per `contact`
- The `survey` has a column called `scheduled_at` with time data

I want a query off `Surveys` with one instance per `contact`, where that `survey` has the recent most scheduled_at compared to other instances with the same `contact` foreign key.

While [this seems like a good SQL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship), wondering if there is a cleaner ActiveRecord solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try running following.

```
@contact.surveys.order(scheduled_at: :desc).first(5)
```

This will return the 5 most recent surveys of that order.

Assumption:
@contact is the an object of your Contact model

Comment: The end goal is only 1 `survey` instance per `contact_id` to be returned and that instance has the most recent `scheduled_at`. This only returns it for one `Contact`. I need it to be `Survey` based.

Comment: I am assuming you have `params[:contact_id]` variable and you want most recent survey for this `contact_id` . Try running this code.
`Survey.where(contact_id: params[:contact_id]).order(scheduled_at: :desc).first`

Comment: I have no params. I need the most recent survey for each contact, not just one.

Comment: Use this 
`Contacts.find_each do |contact| latest_survey_array << contact.surveys.order(scheduled_at: :desc).first end`
I hope this will work for you.
`latest_survey_array` will have all the latest surveys for each contact

Comment: While that retrieves the proper records I want to do so with `ActiveRecord` (as outlined above).