# How can I apply LIMIT/ORDER conditions to an ActiveRecord Join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Currently I have a `Conversation has many Messages` relationship, and a `User has many Conversations` relationship.

I would like to create an ActiveRecord Query to get *The Last Message of each conversation* that a user has.

Let's say I have the conversations *ids* in an array...

```
ids = [24, 22, 23]
```

This query:

```
Message.where(conversation_id: ids).joins(:conversation).order(created_at: :desc)
```

... is correct in terms that it returns ALL the Messages across all the user's conversations.

Using the same query above, If I map an array of the `conversation_id`s:

```
Message.where(conversation_id: ids).joins(:conversation).order(created_at: :desc).map(&:conversation_id)
```

I get an array like this: `[24, 24, 22, 22, 23, 22]` that tells me there are 3 messages in conversation with conversation_id=22, 2 messages with conversation_id=24, 1 with conversation_id=23.

This is good, But now my Question now is, **How can I create an ActiveRecord Query to get just One Message from each Conversation? (the last one that was created)**

I assume I have to use the `limit()`/`order()` methods, but I have no idea how to do it, it's a little too advanced for me.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joins` can accept a string, and you can specify any join you want as plain text. See [doco](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins).

Example:

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.bookmarkable_type = 'Post' AND bookmarks.user_id = users.id")
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.bookmarkable_type = 'Post' AND bookmarks.user_id = users.id
```

As for the problem of joining to the latest record, that's another question in it's own right, and has an answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship).

Example:

```
SELECT  c.*, p.*
FROM    customer c INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_id,
                    MAX(date) MaxDate
            FROM    purchase
            GROUP BY customer_id
        ) MaxDates ON c.id = MaxDates.customer_id INNER JOIN
        purchase p ON   MaxDates.customer_id = p.customer_id
                    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.date
```

Comment: Quick question, does this solution apply if I want to retrieve the N-Last records?

Comment: To be honest, of the top of my head I'm not sure how you'd do that

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It appears there isn't an easy solution to this problem available, at least not one that doesn't rely on having to write/embed SQL into Ruby, quite unfortunate.

Comment: You could just denormalise your database, and store the 'last_message_id' field on each row of your conversations table. It's not best practices strictly speaking, but it's sometimes the most practical thing to do.

Comment: I agree, but I will need the N-last, not just the last. Otherwise, I agree that option would be perfect.

Comment: Since there's no RoR answer to this question, I will accept yours. Thank you very much for your kind help!