# Sql find lasted id on OneToMany relation ship

Tags: mysql, sql

i just learn about how can i get latest inserted id in relation ship with this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111420/1830228), in database i have two table as `channel_content_type` and `channel_plain_text_container`, each `channel_plain_text_container` row referenced to `channel_content_type` with `content_id` column on `id` of `channel_content_type`

that means `channel_content_type` have more row on `channel_plain_text_container` as has many, now how can i find lastest inserted id in that?

this sql command is not correct and return no any row

```
SELECT ptext.id
FROM channel_content_type content
JOIN channel_plain_text_container ptext ON (content.id = ptext.content_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN channel_content_type p2 ON (content.id = p2.id)
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your result by the Id on a descending order and get the top row:

```
SELECT  ptext.id
FROM channel_content_type content
JOIN channel_plain_text_container ptext ON (content.id = ptext.content_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN channel_content_type p2 ON (content.id = p2.id)
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
Order by ptext.id desc
```

In the above query the `Order by ptext.id desc` sorts the result by the id, in a descending order. The firs row in the result set contains the result that you expect.

Comment: I made a change in the query. Please try it again

Comment: Does your original query return any results?

Comment: soooo...when you add the last line (order by ptext.id desc), the result is null but without that line, it is returning some data? really? Does the query generate any errors?

Comment: command work fine without any problem, i think problem is `WHERE p2.id IS NULL`, because after remove this line from command i get result

Comment: Since I don't know anything about  your DB and the logic behind the query, I can't comment about the where clause. My solution to your question remains the same... order it by Id in a descending order and read the first row. Best of luck!