# Laravel Implement greatest-n-per-group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**User** table:

```
| id |       name | age |
|----|------------|-----|
|  1 |      Apple |  22 |
|  2 | Strawberry |  23 |
|  3 |     Orange |  50 |
|  4 |      Mango |  30 |
```

**Memberships** table:

```
| id | user_id |            expire_at |
|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |       1 | 2019-08-17T11:19:30Z |
|  2 |       1 | 2019-08-10T11:20:10Z |
|  3 |       2 | 2019-08-29T11:20:19Z |
|  4 |       3 | 2019-08-02T11:20:30Z |
|  5 |       3 | 2019-08-28T11:20:40Z |
```

---

### Problom

**I want select users with the latest 'expire_at'.**

After reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111420/5588637,
I tried the following:

```sql
SELECT
    u.*,
    m1.* 
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN memberships m1 ON u.id = m1.user_id
    LEFT JOIN memberships m2 ON u.id = m2.user_id 
    AND ( 
        m1.expire_at < m2.expire_at 
        OR m1.expire_at = m2.expire_at 
        AND m1.id < m2.id 
        ) 
WHERE
    m2.id IS NULL;
```

#### Result

> The `id` will appear twice because I used to `join`.

```
| id |       name | age | id | user_id |            expire_at |
|----|------------|-----|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |      Apple |  22 |  1 |       1 | 2019-08-17T11:19:30Z |
|  2 | Strawberry |  23 |  3 |       2 | 2019-08-29T11:20:19Z |
|  3 |     Orange |  50 |  5 |       3 | 2019-08-28T11:20:40Z |
```

After change  `m1.*` to `m1.expire_at`. I got the result I want.

```
| id |       name | age |            expire_at |
|----|------------|-----|----------------------|
|  1 |      Apple |  22 |  2019-08-17T11:19:30Z|
|  2 | Strawberry |  23 | 2019-08-29T11:20:19Z |
|  3 |     Orange |  50 | 2019-08-28T11:20:40Z |
```

> online try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27fa22/4

---

### Implement in Lavavel

> Laravel Framework version: 5.6.39

I am trying to convert the above SQL into Laravel using [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).

```php
$users = DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.*', 'm1.*')
            ->join('memberships as m1','u.id','=','m1.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('memberships as m2', function($join){
                $join->on('u.id', '=', 'm2.user_id')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('m1.expire_at','<','m2.expire_at')
                    ->orWhere('m1.expire_at','=','m2.expire_at')
                    ->where('m1.id','<','m2.id');
                });
            })
            ->whereNull('m2.id')
            ->toSQL();
```

> I'm using `toSql()`. This will convert it to SQL first  to make sure it's same of above SQL.

```sql
SELECT
    `u`.*,
    `m1`.* 
FROM
    `users` AS `u`
    INNER JOIN `memberships` AS `m1` ON `u`.`id` = `m1`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `memberships` AS `m2` ON `u`.`id` = `m2`.`user_id` 
    AND (
        `m1`.`expire_at` < ? 
        OR `m1`.`expire_at` = ? 
        AND `m1`.`id` < ?
        ) 
WHERE
    `m2`.`id` IS NULL
```

> `?` seems to be the characteristic of laravel, I believe it is same of above SQL.

when i change `toSQL()` to `get()`, the result following:

```sh
Collection { ▼
  #items: []
}
```

The above result is wrong, so i tried **remove** 
`whereNull('m2.id')` in Laravel code  (`WHERE m2.id IS NULL` in SQL), let’s see what happened.

**Laravel result**

```sql
Collection { ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => { ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "Apple"
      +"age": "Eric Yiu SL"
      +"user_id": 1
      +"expire_at": "2019-08-10T11:20:10Z"
    }
    ...
]
```

**Ideal result**

```
| id |       name | age | id | user_id |            expire_at |
|----|------------|-----|----|---------|----------------------|
|  1 |      Apple |  22 |  2 |       1 | 2019-08-10T11:20:10Z |
|  3 |     Orange |  50 |  4 |       3 | 2019-08-02T11:20:30Z |
|  1 |      Apple |  22 |  1 |       1 | 2019-08-17T11:19:30Z |
|  2 | Strawberry |  23 |  3 |       2 | 2019-08-29T11:20:19Z |
|  3 |     Orange |  50 |  5 |       3 | 2019-08-28T11:20:40Z |
```

Comparing results, **Laravel result** missing second id which is memberships table id, i guess this is the reason of incorrect results.

I have searched the Internet, seems is this problem.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4962

But I failed after various attempts...

Comment: What happens if you select only `->select('u.*', 'm1.expire_at')`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select two rows with the same name in Laravel. The second one will override the first one. Use an alias instead.

```
$users = DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.*', 'm1.id as membership_id')
            ->join('memberships as m1','u.id','=','m1.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('memberships as m2', function($join){
                $join->on('u.id', '=', 'm2.user_id')
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->whereColumn('m1.expire_at','<','m2.expire_at')
                            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->whereColumn('m1.expire_at','=','m2.expire_at')
                                    ->whereColumn('m1.id','<','m2.id');
                            });
                    });
            })
            ->whereNull('m2.id')
            ->get();
```

*Note: I also encapsulated the `orWhere()` in the join to avoid confusion about the order of AND/OR.*

What also works is using a different order in the select. You can for example use the following:

```
$query->select([
    'm1.*',
    'm1.id as membership_id',
    'u.*'
])
```

It will return all columns of both tables plus the new `membership_id` column. But if there is a column on the `users` table which is named similarly to a column on the `memberships` table, only the `users` table column is returned (e.g. `created_at`). What comes last in your list is returned.

Comment: Most likely indeed the problem here as array elements will be overriden when using the same keys.. Everybody should know why using `SELECT *` generally is a bad idea, especially in frameworks where you don't know how the code will handle duplicated colum names..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't think that's a Laravel issue. PHP (like pretty much every language) cannot have duplicate keys on objects and arrays, which means that both `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` (and all the others) won't be able to hold all requested columns. But you are totally right, it's a nice example why `SELECT *` is not the best idea after all. :)

Comment: i know i edited the comment before your posted your comment, but you are totally right its a PHP language "limitation" but because off the Laraval layer "you lose track" what happens on the lower level (native PHP) and you assume Laraval will handle this column name duplication under the hood..

Comment: I also post this question on githiub-laravel and had different answers. Everyone's answer can also have correct results.
Link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29625

Thanks your help!!!

Comment: What an unfortunate oversight on my end. Of course you need `whereColumn`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As @Namoshek mentioned, you should not select everything because you have a duplicate key problem in your SQL query. I modified my answer so that it would match @RaymondNijland answer. And by the way, even for the table user, you should select exactly what you need. And not only for a duplicate key problem but also for the speed of your SQL query. We don't think about it enough but it can quickly make the difference on a big set of results.

Less data to send from the database to your PHP server = faster

---

You should try this one :

```
DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.*', 'm1.id as membership_id')
            ->join('memberships as m1','u.id','=','m1.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('memberships as m2', function ($join) {
                $join->on('u.id', '=', 'm2.user_id')
                    ->on(function($join) {
                        $join->on('m1.id', '<', 'm2.id')
                            ->on(function($join) {
                                $join->on('m1.expire_at', '<', 'm2.expire_at')
                                    ->orOn('m1.expire_at', '=', 'm2.expire_at');
                            });
                    });
            })
            ->whereNull('m2.id')
            ->toSQL()
```

As mentioned in Laravel's documentation on this page: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on

You can pass a closure to the `on()` method and there is the `orOn()` method that you can use in this closure.

I tested it and it gives the same result as your SQL query.

Comment: @Namoshek wrote a answer not me, i just commented and removed that comment about the column duplication.. ..