# How do I optimize this SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, optimization

The following query gets all the forum posts of a category. And I also need to display the latest comment time for each post. But the query seem to take more time to make because of it. (which makes sense).

But I am not able to figure out how I can optimize it, and I'm not sure where to look for information on this.
Any tips or solutions to my problem would be greatly appreciated.

**Query to get the initial posts for the category**

```
var query = context.ctm_Forum_Post.Where(x => x.Deleted == false && x.FK_Categori_ID == Id)
    .Select(x => new ForumPostModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Title = x.Title,
        BodyText = x.BodyText,
        Summary = x.Summary,
        Archieved = x.Archieved,
        Created = x.Created,
        Deleted = x.Deleted,
        MemberID = x.FK_Member_ID,
        Sticky = x.Sticky,
        Updated = x.Updated,
        CategoryId = x.FK_Categori_ID
    }).ToList();

foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.LatestCommentTime = this.GetNewestCommentDateByPost(item.Id);
}
return query.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Created);
```

And for each and every post I have to make one more call to the database.

```
 var query = (from comments in context.ctm_Comments
                                 join posts in context.ctm_Forum_Post on comments.Page_ID equals posts.Id
                                 where posts.Id == id && comments.Deleted == false
                                 orderby comments.Reqistration_timestamp descending
                                 select comments.Reqistration_timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Comments table**

```
 public partial class ctm_Comments
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Page_ID { get; set; }
        public int Member_ID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Reqistration_timestamp { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> Page_Guid { get; set; }
    }
```

**Post table**

```
public partial class ctm_Forum_Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string BodyText { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public int FK_Categori_ID { get; set; }
        public bool Archieved { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public bool Sticky { get; set; }
        public int FK_Member_ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ctm_Forum_Category ctm_Forum_Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: An [mre] is always nice. Imagine if I had a `Forum_Post`, `Post`, `Comment` class with only key and fk, the used properties (eg deleted, timestamp), and one bogus property to identify them. We could also have simple list initialsiation with 1 post, 2 comments.

Comment: Here I think I will not try to make LinQ2Sql write the query. I will do a simple procedure or a view for the lazy. But going 100% sql to avoid any issue during the translation.

Comment: I added the two tables @DragandDrop

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: and for the linq grouped join : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins

Comment: Here is how to do it in memory https://dotnetfiddle.net/kZx9Xi. This solution does not care about translated sql.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pull all in one query? Why don't you pull latest 10-20 posts using paging that will make query fast and then use a separate query to pull comments of that post?

And in case you need to pull large data then I would suggest to use a stored procedure as that is optimized with the fast execution plan.

I am not sure why you are using Join to pull comments, you can add Post ID in Comment field and then use a simple query to pull comments of that post without using Joins unless you are not trying to pull other data from Post table..

Comment: I think I joined because I was trying to get it all in one query, and then when I couldn't I just forgot to remove it ^^

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

add `Reqistration_timestamp` property to `ForumPostModel`

```
public class ForumPostModel
{
    //other property............................... 
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Reqistration_timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

query

```
var query = context.ctm_Forum_Posts
         .Join(context.ctm_Comments,
         post => post.Id,
         comment => comment.Page_ID,
         (post, comment) => new
         {
             p = post,
             c = comment
         }
        ).Where(x => x.p.Deleted == false && x.p.FK_Categori_ID == Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.c.Reqistration_timestamp).Take(1)
        .Select(x => new ForumPostModel()
        {
           Id = x.p.Id,
           Title = x.p.Title,
           BodyText = x.p.BodyText,
           Summary = x.p.Summary,
           Archieved = x.p.Archieved,
           Created = x.p.Created,
           Deleted = x.p.Deleted,
           MemberID = x.p.FK_Member_ID,
           Sticky = x.p.Sticky,
           Updated = x.p.Updated,
           CategoryId = x.p.FK_Categori_ID,
           LatestCommentTime = this.GetNewestCommentDateByPost(x.p.Id),
           Reqistration_timestamp = x.c.Reqistration_timestamp
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ToList();
```