# PostgreSQL join to most recent record between tables

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

I have two tables pertaining to this question: `conversations` has many `messages`.  The basic structure (with just the relevant columns) is as follows:

```
conversations (
  int id (PK)
)

create table conversation_participants (
  int id (PK),
  int conversation_id (FK conversations),
  int user_id (FK users),
  unique key on [conversation_id, profile_id]
)

create table messages (
  int id (PK),
  int conversation_id (FK conversations),
  int sender_id (FK users),
  int recipient_id (FK users),
  text body
)
```

For each conversations entry, given a `user_id` I want to receive:

- all conversations that user participated in (i.e.: `conversations.*`)
- joined to the most recent matching message (i.e.: `order by messages.id desc limit 1`)
- conversations ordered by their most recent message id (i.e.: order by `messages.id desc`)

Unfortunately, all the query help I can seem to find on anything like this pertains to MySQL, and that doesn't work in PostgreSQL.  The closest thing I found is [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734804/107277) that gives an example of the `select distinct on (...)` syntax.  However, unless I'm just doing it wrong, I can't seem to get the results ordered in the correct way given the grouping constraints I need with that method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All information is in the table "messages", you don't need the other tables:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    body,
    c.* -- content from conversations 
FROM messages 
    JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, conversation_id 
        FROM messages 
        WHERE 1 IN(sender_id, recipient_id) -- the number is the userid, should be dynamic
        GROUP BY conversation_id) sub
        USING(id, conversation_id)
    JOIN conversations c ON c.id = messages.conversation_id
ORDER BY
    id DESC;
```

Edit: Just JOIN on "conversations" to get the data needed from this table.

Comment: There is actually other information in the `conversations` table that I need.  At the beginning of my post, I tried to say that I've only included tables/columns relevant to the join, but perhaps that made it confusing in the sense that it wasn't clear that there's more data I'll be selecting than is shown here.  Unfortunately, this method won't work for me because of that.

Comment: Check the new query, it's joined on "converstations" as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select
    *
from
    conversation_participants cp

    join conversations c on
    c.id = cp.conversation_id

    -- assuming you only want the conversations where a
    -- message has been left. otherwise use left join
    join messages m on
    m.conversation_id = cp.conversation_id
    and m.id = (
            select
                    id
            from
                    messages _m
            where
                    _m.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
                    and sender_id = 1
            order by
                    id desc
            limit 1
    )
where
        cp.user_id = 1
order by
        m.id desc;
```