# Selecting more info from the same row after using GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing, for example, this data:

```
id | value | name   | date
1  | 1     | 'one'  | 2015-01-02
2  | 1     | 'two'  | 2015-02-03
3  | 2     | 'three'| 2014-01-03
4  | 2     | 'four' | 2014-01-02
```

I want for each distinct value, the name of the row with the latest date. So:

```
value | name   | date
1     | 'two'  | 2015-02-03
2     | 'three'| 2014-01-03
```

I currently have this query: `SELECT value, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY value`, which gives me the value and date columns I'm looking for. How do I modify the query to add the name field? Simply adding it to the `SELECT` clause won't work, as Postgres will (understandably) complain I have to add it to the `GROUP BY` clause. But doing so will add it to the uniqueness check, and my query will return all 4 rows. All I need is the name of the row where it found the latest date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient latest record query with Postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684244/efficient-latest-record-query-with-postgresql)  Several good examples already exist for this type of question.

Comment: Hi Jorn. my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct on()` is the most efficient way to do this with Postgres

```
select distinct on (value) id, value, name, date
from the_table
order by value, date;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dff68/1

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all required fields:

```
select t1.* from table t1 
inner join (
  SELECT value, MAX(date) as date FROM table GROUP BY value
 )t2 on t1.date=t2.date;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9491f/2

Comment: I don't think so. I want a `MAX(date)`, not `MAX(id)`, meaning I can't do the join you're proposing.

Comment: What if you have two same date for single value?